# Python privilégios de administrador

Tags: python, python-3.x

Existe alguma forma ou comando para se executar um script em Python com privilégios de administrador?

Comment: Sua pergunta está ampla demais ou não parece ser sobre programação.

Comment: Qual sistema operacional utilizado? Está enfrentando algum problema ao rodar o código normalmente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se estiver no linux, basta executar com sudo:

```
sudo python meuScript.py
```

No caso do windows(já que você mencionou administrador em vez de root, suponho que seja esse o caso), existem algumas opções:

1. Você pode executar o terminal com privilégios de administrador.

   Iniciar -> cmd -> clica com o direito -> Executar como administrador.

Você também pode apertar CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER após digitar cmd. Após isso, basta executar o script normalmente.

2. Fazer o próprio script pedir por privilégios de administrador:

```
    import os
    import sys
    import win32com.shell.shell as shell
    ASADMIN = 'asadmin'


    if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
        script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
        params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
        shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
```

Fonte: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows)