# Como abrir um programa como admin no Python

Tags: python

Galera eu queria fazer um script que abra o cmd como admin e digite um comando (por exemplo ipconfig).

Comment: Dá uma olhada neste link, talvez ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174692/python-privil%C3%A9gios-de-administrador

Comment: Da uma olhada na biblioteca de subprocess do python. Fica o link abaixo da documentação:
[Documentação SubProcess Python](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)